# Working out the safe continuous discharge current for a lead acid battery

Tags: batteries

I have a [Numax DC25MF 12v lead acid battery](https://www.tayna.co.uk/leisure-batteries/numax/dc25mf/) with a quoted capacity of 95Ah (C20)

What is the continuous safe discharge current for the battery? By 'continuous' I mean a few hours without a break, and by 'safe' I mean without shortening the life of the battery.

I can't find the figure quoted anywhere (not directly anyway) and the only Numax [datasheet](https://cdn.taynabatteries.eu/datasheets/NUMAX-Leisure-Datasheet.pdf) I can find doesn't actually mention the DC25MF model.

Can I simply divide 95 by 20 and assume it'safe to discharge at 4.75 amps?

Answer (score 0):

Lead acid batteries in cars do not need a CC limit but do have a CV limit as in cars. 14.2 for flooded cells.

Follow the link on the page you gave for maintenance tips.

### the C20 rate is 95Ah in 20 h so a few A will last 95Ah/few A=__ h

https://www.tayna.co.uk/tutorials/caring-for-your-battery

Comment: The DC25MF is not a car battery, it's a leisure battery and it should be possible to run it for more many hours at a modest current drain (i.e. a few amps) the question is, how many amps?